# How to restore triples accidentally deleted from Virtuoso DB?

Tags: restore, virtuoso

I accidentally deleted records from a Virtuoso graph DB. Does anyone know how to undo the delete and restore the data?

Answer (score 0):

In the simple default case, you cannot undo a delete such as you describe.

If you were taking backups, and have one from the right point in time, you can restore that.

If you were retaining transaction logs or other audit trail, you can replay these.

More details about your specific situation may change some of the above answers, but this is unlikely.

(ObDisclaimer: [OpenLink Software](https://www.openlinksw.com/) produces [Virtuoso](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/), and employs me.)